# Edit Bootstrap modal form without jQuery - ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, bootstrap-modal

I've created a bootstrap popup modal form without jQuery.

This works with a non modal form:

```
<td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "AddOrEdit", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })</td>
```

However, I would like to be able to edit the form as a modal form. I've tried the code below, but it just brings up an empty modal form. It's not even hitting the controller

```
<td><button class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#addInfo" data-toggle="modal" data-path="@Url.Action("Edit", "AddOrEdit", new { id = item.Id })"></button></td>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Below is my full code

```
   <div class="panel-body">
   <table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Reference</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th><button class="btn btn-success text-white" data-target="#addInfo" data-toggle="modal"><i class="fas fa-random" /> Create New</button></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Entity)
    {
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>@item.Reference</td>
                <td>@item.Name</td>
                <td>@item.Description</td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-primary" data target="#addInfo" data-toggle="modal" data-path="@Url.Action("AddOrEdit", "Index", new { id = item.Id })">click</button></td>                        
                
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    }

</table>
```

```
   <div class="modal" id="addInfo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
     <div class="modal-dialog" data-keyboard="false" role="document">
       <div class="modal-content" id="modalBody">

         <partial name="AddOrEditInfo" />

        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to click to pop up a modal window with content?
If you can refer to this.

```
<td><button class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#addInfo" data-toggle="modal" data-path="@Url.Action("Test", "Index", new { id = 1 })">click</button></td>


<div class="modal fade" id="addInfo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              Test
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxyCA.png)

Comment: Thank you NMSL. I've updated my code with your suggestion - See full code. I would like to add this code to the edit button. With the code above, the modal form opens up when I click on edit button, but still does not populate the form. I don't think the Url.Action method is being executed

Comment: Yes, in what form do you want to fill the modal window with data?You can write the filling content in <div class="modal-body">comment</div>.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. The Modal form opens up alright, but it  is not populated with data.